Include stock status in drop for for size attribute when using variation swatches
Our site is using variation swatches consistently across most of our products.
I am looking to add a stock status next to our sizes variation.
When we werent using swatches using the woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html hook natively was working, however now that we are using swatches, this method no longer works.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'variations_options_html_callback', 30, 2);

function variations_options_html_callback( $html, $args ){

$args = wp_parse_args( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args ), array(
        'options' => false,
        'attribute' => false,
        'product' => false,
        'selected' => false,
        'name' => '',
        'id' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'show_option_none' => __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ),
    ));
.
.
.
}

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can add customisations to the drop-downs public function to achieve this.
https://kaikoadesigns.com.au/product/sail-away/

What you are asking is logically not possible when there is more than one attribute for variation: In your website linked product as you have "sizes" (select field) and "colors" (swatches)… What about if for a given size you have a different stock status depending on the color (for example, "in stock" for "Silver" and "out of stock" for "Gold")? So not possible…

Noted. I see that now. I dont know how I could have missed that.

In my example, sizes is prioritised over material and carat. Logically if the variations were reordered  as material, carat and then size this might be achievable the right? since the relationship to the final variation would be established by the first two selections?

No, this can only work if you have a unique attribute set for variations... As you have 2 (or more), it's not possible. Now if you build something completely custom with mandatory progressive steps like: First step: material selection, 2nd step: carat selection and last step: size selection, then you should be able in some way to add dynamically a stock status to each size using JavaScript.
